# How to return the value of Automatic when it is used in a Mathematica function?

Tags: options

If I have a function, for example:

```
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[S[t]*10^-12 /. sol], {t, 20 10^-9, 49 10^-9}]
```

and this function is setting options->Automatic so the function arguments are implicitly:

```
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[S[t]*10^-12 /. sol], {t, 20 10^-9, 49 10^-9}, 
          PlotPoints->Automatic, MaxRecursion->Automatic]
```

how do I get the value to which Automatic has been set?

Comment: You can look at `Options[p1]` although this can sometime also show `Automatic` for some of internal options.

Comment: @Nasser That will only tell me that an option has been set to Automatic. I want to know what that value is.

Comment: It should be `AbsoluteOptions[p1, PlotPoints]`, but `AbsoluteOptions[]`  has a lot of bugs and doesn't work for `PlotPoints`

Comment: @belisarius `AbsoluteOptions[p1, PlotPoints]` returns empty for `p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> Automatic]` on windows, V 10.01. So you are right, it has a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option is to use `Trace` to find occurrences of the relevant rules which appear during evaluation:

```
Trace[
 Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
 HoldPattern[PlotPoints | MaxRecursion -> _],
 TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union
```

> {MaxRecursion -> 6, MaxRecursion -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotPoints -> Automatic}

Or you can set `"Verbose" -> True` in the system visualisation options to get lots of internal information as the plot is created:

```
SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}]
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> (0.): >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Plot <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>
> (0.): Expr to Evaluate:
>
> {Sin[t],{{t,0,2π}, Mesh->None, Exclusions->Automatic, PlotPoints->50, MaxRecursion->6, Filling->None, ColorFunction->...

Answer (score 8):

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

From the documentation at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Options.html the default for `PlotPoints` is 50.

To determine the default for `MaxRecursion`, let

```
f[x_] = Product[x + n (-1)^n, {n, -4, 5}] E^(-x^2/2);
```

The number of points for the `Plot` of `f[x]` with the defaults for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` is

```
auto = Cases[Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 4}, PlotRange -> All], 
   Line[pts_] :> Length[pts], Infinity][[1]]
```

> 1154

With the default `PlotPoints` and varying `MaxRecursion` check for the same number of points:

```
Select[
 Cases[
     Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 4},
      PlotRange -> All,
      MaxRecursion -> #],
     Line[pts_] :> {#, Length[pts]},
     Infinity][[1]] & /@ Range[15],
 #[[2]] == auto &]
```

> {{6, 1154}}

Hence, the default `MaxRecursion` is 6

Comment: I remembered now the `Cases[...Line[pts_]` method. I forgot all about it before. Much better than using index.

Answer (score 3):

When all else fail, i.e. `Options[p1]` or `AbsoluteOptions[p1, PlotPoints]`, you can always grab the Line itself and find how many points it has:

```
 p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotPoints -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 line = p1[[1, 1, 3, 2]];
 Graphics[line]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Length[line[[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, 259 points are used in this case.

```
 ListPlot[line[[1]], Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that M oversamples where the function changes *most*, as expected.
ps. this is not the recommended way to find number of points used, since internal data structure can change, and index used above can become invalid in future versions.

Comment: @belisarius I am not following you, sorry. Let me think. I need coffee. But what I see is more points are used where the function changes most. (I mean near the top)

Comment: Get your coffee. The function is almost flat at the top.

Comment: @Nasser This helps, but I still would like to know the value of MaxRecursion->Automatic. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: @Nasser Actually, I think this method doesn't return the value of PlotPoints, rather PlotPoints*(MaxRecursion+1).

Comment: Sorry, that gives the maximum number of points used in the plot. The code: Length[line[[1]]], will give a value between PlotPoints and PlotPoints*(MaxRecursion+1)...I think.