# Getting PlotPoints value from a Plot

Tags: plotting, properties

I want to display the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` values used to plot the current graph so that the user can change the values relatively to improve the output. Is it possible to get the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` information from a plot?

```
a = 
  Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2]

PlotRange[a]
PlotPoints[a]
MaxRecursion[a]
```

Comment: Options[a,PlotRange].

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions` can help a little.You can get the value of `PlotRange` like this `AbsoluteOptions[a, PlotRange]`But the value of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` Maybe be vanished after you get the `a`.

Comment: If the goal is to expose these values to users, you might try to pass them to the `PlotLabel` too. Or you could pass them to a combined `Text` graphic as shown in the 3rd example on [howTo/MakeASmootherOrRougherPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/MakeASmootherOrRougherPlot.html). This shows a dynamic example with labels for `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`.

Comment: my requirement is, to first plot the graph using Automatic. And if the user is not satisfied with the result, he could change the options. For the user to easily change the option values, I thought it would be good to show them the current values.

Comment: If you are trying to make an interactive application where the user can control certain plot parameter, you should simply take control by explicitly giving values for those parameters that user will permitted to change.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes that is one way to do it. However using Automatic at first will produce better plots than any fixed number. Is there someway to calculate PlotPoints based on the number of points seen in FullForm[a] ?

Comment: As far I know there is no way to get the values used for `MaxRecursion` or `PlotPoints` from the result of evaluating a `Plot` expression.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this,

```
SetAttributes[verbosePlot, HoldAll]
verbosePlot[plotcommand_] := Module[{plot, pp, mr},
  {pp, mr} = {PlotPoints, 
     MaxRecursion} /. (Trace[plot = plotcommand, 
         HoldPattern[(MaxRecursion -> _Integer) | (PlotPoints -> _Integer)],
         TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Reverse // 
      ReleaseHold);
  Print@*Row /@ {{"MaxRecursions \[Rule] ", 
     mr}, {"PlotPoints \[Rule] ", pp}, {"PlotRange \[Rule] ", 
     Charting`get2DPlotRange@plotcommand}};
  plot
  ]
```

Here we are using `Trace` to find the actual values of `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` used, and the undocumented function `` Charting`get2DPlotRange@plotcommand `` to get the `PlotRange` (a different method is needed for this option since `Trace` will return `PlotRange->All` if that is the option given).

Thanks to Simon Woods for this [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66988/9490), and thanks to J.M. for the tips on improving it.  This will plot the command and give the values for the requested option.

```
verbosePlot[Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]

another example,

```
verbosePlot[
 ParametricPlot[
  r^2 { Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {r, 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

If you want to extract the option values from an already created plot, I don't know how to do that.  The only information available in the `FullForm` of the plot would be the number of mesh points, not the algorithm used to generate them.

Note that you can also bypass this user-defined function and go straight to `TracePrint`,

```
TracePrint[
 ParametricPlot[
  r^2 {Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {r, 1, 
   2}], (MaxRecursion -> _Integer) | (PlotPoints -> _Integer), 
 TraceInternal -> True]
Charting`get2DPlotRange@%
```

[image]

if you don't mind the duplicated results from `TracePrint`

Comment: I would like to know how did you know the usage of the functions that located in context **Charting**. Thanks:)

Comment: I got ``Charting`get2DPlotRange`` and ``Charting`get3DPlotRange`` from hanging around here, very useful functions. I don't know what else is in the ``Charting` `` package though

Comment: @ShutaoTANG - but there do seem to be a **lot** of them:  ``Names["Charting`*"]``

Comment: In general, I using ``?Charting` `` :) A few days ago, I saw this function in your [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112656/mathematica-flip-the-axes-ticks-negative-values-to-other-side/112659#112659)

Comment: Ahhh, but these are undocumented functions, so you won't find any documentation that way :-D

Comment: Yes, they are undocumented, so I think these functions are designed for the WRI developers, rather than the general users.

Comment: For your perusal: `TracePrint[Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}], (MaxRecursion -> _Integer) | (PlotPoints -> _Integer), TraceInternal -> True]`. You can then apply ``Charting`get2DPlotRange[]`` to the output afterwards. (N.B. `PlotRange[graphics]` and ``Charting`get2DPlotRange[graphics]`` will have different results in general, depending on the `PlotRangePadding` setting.)

Comment: @J.M. , any idea why `PlotPoints /. 
 Flatten@Trace[
   plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 
      2 \[Pi]}], (MaxRecursion -> _Integer) | (PlotPoints -> _Integer), TraceInternal -> True]` doesn't work?  It claims that "..... is not a list of replacement rules", but `Head /@{PlotPoints -> 50, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
  MaxRecursion -> 6}` returns `{Rule, Rule, Rule, Rule}`

Comment: Did you have a look at the `FullForm[]` of the output of `Flatten[(* stuff *)]`?

Comment: @J.M. also I went for the charting option since if you give `PlotRange->All`, then `Trace` doesn't seem to give any numeric values.

Comment: Yes, I was merely anticipating people who might ask why you didn't just extract `PlotRange` from the resulting `Graphics[]` object.

Comment: Nice (+1). `PlotRange` works as a function for both 2D and 3D plots.

Comment: @kglr, that's what I told Jason; the only snag in that is that it doesn't account for `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, I missed that, I wanted to make it versatile but the Charting functions only work for 2D **or** 3D. I will check later, but is it the case that `PlotRange` will return the exact range given if you state it explicitly. But also give a numeric range if you use `Automatic` or `Full`?

Comment: @JasonB thanks for the answer. But the TracePrint is not working for RegionPlot[reg] cases. For example, RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x > 10 && y < 10, {x, y}]]